# Using Regex to match indefinite strings in two locations of a regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to match expressions of the form

```
set _ on(\s*)set _ off
```

where both underscores `_` stand in for a single contiguous string.

The idea is to match things such as the following:

> set foo on blah halb set foo off
>
> set bar on set bar on set bar on set bar off

the important thing is that these directives, in my case, start by being set on and end by being set off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do back references in perl:

```
m/^\s*set\s*(\w*)\s*on.*set\s*\1\s*off\s*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
set\s[^\s]+\son
set\s[^\s]+\soff
```

Explanation: `[^\s]+` matches a string that does not contain a space. `set\s[^\s]+\son` matches anything like `set foo on`, but not `set foo bar on` or `set on`. Combining the above expressions will match whatever you wanted.

which kind of regex are you using?

Comment: I'm using grepwin. I'm having trouble understanding why your suggestion would work,

Comment: @DavidPerlaza I might misunderstand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could clarify: (i) do you look for pair of matching `set xxx... on` ... `set xxx off` directives, where `xxx` is the same? or (ii) do you want to catch all occurrences of `set xxx (on|off)`?

Comment: both. currently i'm struggling with an aspect of (ii), which is ensuring that the files to be searched start with set xxx on and ultimately end with set xxx off, without having, say, a set xxx on after having set xxx off. Any behavior in between is fine. 
The following regex takes care of (i) using a back reference:
set (.*) on(\s*)set \1 off
Forgive me for any obfuscation, and thanks for a response!

Answer (score 0):

```
^(set bar on)|(set bar off)$
```

Breakdown:

```
^(set bar on) = Looks for "set bar on" at the beginning of a string
(set bar off)$ = Looks for "set bar off" at the end of the string.
```

This will match a `set bar on` at the beginning of the string and `set bar off` at the end of the string.  You can do a replace to change them to a blank character `""` and then pull the remaining data out for your match.  I don't know what you are using for your regex implementation, so I can't help you much beyond this.  You can also add `\s` at the beginning and end if you want to remove the spaces after `set bar on` and before `set bar off`.